# My Android App Crashes

Tags: android, debugging

I have developed a *free* Android app and placed in on the market. I have fully tested the app on one device (LG Ally) and tested it with the whole range of emulators. I am getting reports of crashes on some 2.2 devices. The people reporting the crashes are not being at all helpful. I am looking for some expert help here.

The application and a description of the problems can be found at:

[BASIC! v00.03](http://laughton.com/basic/versions/v00.03/index.html)

If having access to the source would help, send me an email.

Any help that could be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you with the information you've provided?

Comment: Use ACRA (http://code.google.com/p/acra/), Flurry, or something to automatically collect stack traces from your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have any of your users submitted an error report?  Usually that will include a stack trace of some sort to give you an idea of what is causing the error.

Comment: Thank. I did not know about the feature of the reports. I will start there.

Comment: The stack traces helped a lot. Most of the bugs have been solved. I have also added ACRA to most crashes.